# How can I get an R-squared value of 1 (fit 100%)?

Tags: regression, variance, excel

I have a set of data and plotted it in a graph (in Microsoft Excel) and then added a trendline. The equation I got is $y=833.71x^{-1.448}$ with $R^2=0.9511$. What should I do to get $R^2=1$ (100% fit)?

Comment: Why do you want R-squared to be 1. That's the ideal case.

Comment: I know, but I am not that advance in statistics. See, I need the coefficient (833.71 and 1.448) as a constant specific related to one site condition. From the graph I only get R-squared=0.9511 and I need a tool how to get a more ideal coefficient (nearly R-squared=1). Is there any rule of thumb on how to adjust the coefficient to get R-squared closer 1?

Comment: Because you are not a statistician--and few are!--please don't try to ask your question in a technical manner that you think will appeal to statisticians; you will only confuse both them and yourself.  Ask in your own terms: what are your data and what do you want to know about them?

Comment: Even without any statistics, so much should be obvious -- if it was possible to meaningfully get $R^2 = 1$ whenever we wanted, *we'd always fit models to do that* - it would be built in to the fitting process. Clearly, then, nobody would ever even need to *compute* $R^2$. It would always be effectively 1. The fact that it is being computed already tells you you can't just "do something" and have it be both 1 (or very close to 1) and meaningful at the same time. [As is true in so many contexts, "if it was that easy, everyone would be doing it". They aren't, so it isn't.]

Comment: You'll get $R^2 = 1$ when all of your data points fall exactly on the predicted line.

Comment: Yes--but obviously they do *not* fall exactly on the line because $R^2\ne 1$.  What, then, are you suggesting?

Comment: I don't think it's obvious to the questioner and a critical point they need to understand. Given that the question was asked I'm not sure they could extract that from the other answers. There are lots of ways to accomplish this.  Most of the answers suggest one (perhaps the most common error). I'm just saying what it would mean as outcome and letting the questioner think about it.

Answer (score 5):

An $R^2 = 1$ indicates perfect fit.  That is, you've explained all of the variance that there is to explain.  In ordinary least squares (OLS) regression (the most typical type), your coefficients are already optimized to maximize the degree of model fit ($R^2$) for your variables and all linear transforms of your variables.  Your model appears to be a little odd in that x is being raised to a particular exponent, so your mileage may vary.  But in response to your general question, you can always get $R^2 = 1$ if you have a number of predicting variables equal to the number of observations, or if you've estimated an intercept the number of observations - 1.  Either way, 20 parameters perfectly describes 20 data points.  Such a model is called [just-identified](http://luna.cas.usf.edu/~mbrannic/files/regression/Pathan.html).  Although this gives you the highly desirable perfect fit... it is essentially meaningless.

Comment: Don't you need to "have a number of predicting variables equal to the number of observations -" ***1***? If you have just 1 observation, you just need the mean to predict it perfectly; if you had 2 observations, you could fit them perfectly w/ 1 predictor variable (a straight line can spear any 2 points); any 3 observations can be fit exactly w/ 2 (any 3 points will fall on some plane), etc.

Comment: @gung: You're right I double counted the intercept.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY want to get 100% R^2, just construct an nth degree polynomial, where n is the sample size. Each degree adds a new kink through one observation. You'll get the 100%, but the model will be meaningless.

Comment: I suspect you mean $(n-1)^{th}$ degree polynomial, don't you?

Comment: Except there is nothing special about it being an nth degree polynomial other than it lets you imagine that in some way everything is still being described by x.  You'd get just as far with n - 1 random variables as predictors so long as no two variables were perfectly correlated.

Comment: @rpierce Nice point (+1), because it gets to the essence of the situation. Note, though, that it is possible for no two variables to be perfectly correlated and yet all $n-1$ random variables might not have full rank, which is what you really want. As an example of the distinction, for $n=4$ take the three variables to be $X$, $Y$, and $Z=X-Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent RVs.

Comment: @whuber: +1;  I hadn't considered that, but now that you mention it, it is obvious.  Thank you.